# How to create task without using Rally.RestApi.dll in C#?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying consume rally REST web service in Windows Phone app. I successfully fetched data using this url "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.36/task?query=((Owner.Name = {0}) and (State != Completed))&order=Rank&fetch=true&stylesheet=/slm/doc/webservice/browser.xsl" and using Ling to Xml I am able to read data. However I am not able to consume Create, Update and Delete operation. Can someone share the code to consume these below service in C#

Create PUT/POST 
XML https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/task/create 
JSON https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/task/create.js

Update POST 
XML https: //rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/task/ObjectID 
JSON https: //rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/task/ObjectID.js

Delete DELETE 
XML https: //rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/task/ObjectID 
JSON https: //rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/task/ObjectID.js

Thanks,
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

Try [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) it supports all the HTTP operations and is available for Windows Phone 7.